# How to find chaos in the World?

Tags: hegel, randomness, progress

My personal impression is that advocates of Hegel's absolute idea or the World inside a computer simulator, have a much easier time proving the balance, common laws and understandable global direction than people trying to prove that, on a grand scale, the World is random and chaotic (not governed by math).
In other words, how to prove that we don't live inside the Matrix?

Comment: Why do you think a simulation will be coherent and logically closed?  Our simulations aren’t.  Inertial physics is not applied to most events in simulations.  No simulated characters or creatures move per Newtonian mechanics, just an approximation that the users are not offended by.

Comment: I think, in any closed simulator, you need to maintain the balance of energies (equation has to balance itself out). This balance can be hidden or spread over centuries. But without a balance of powers, there would be no reason.

Comment: There is no need for any simulation to follow conservation laws. Meanwhile our universe doesn’t either.

Comment: @Dcleve - A 3-year-old child drawing a random picture and thousands of programmers writing the code for Matrix, in my view, are not comparable activities.

Comment: I mean Sony PlayStation 30.. where you can connect to your spinal cord and would have a really hard time distinguishing virtual from a real reality.

Comment: Neither character nor NPC avatars in video games operate under coherent physics. You claim they need to.  This claim is refuted by test.

Comment: Not seeing enough chaos? Just wait.

Comment: You seem to make a mathematical error: from the fact that "P(not Chaos|Matrix) > P(not Chaos|not Matrix)" you are concluding "P(Matrix) > P(not Matrix)."

Comment: If it is a computer simulator, then it has to be built on mathematical equations. And even though mathematics could be beyond human understanding, we still should be able to reverse-engineer it. But it will require hard data, and for that, we need to wait a couple of decades until personal AI assistants can collect hard data about individual lives.

Answer (score 2):

When we assume a deterministic Universe -- a world in which nothing happens at random, but is always caused by something in the past, according to fixed rules<sup>1</sup> -- we assume that this Universe can be understood as a giant, intricate machine, a clockwork. This, however, does not imply that that clockwork must be simulated. It could be, but it does not need to be.

<sup>1</sup> Call them laws of nature, or laws of creation -- they prescribe how causes enact their effects.

Comment: "according to fixed rules" - it is hard to imagine without some kind of intelligent design. Also, the World in computer simulator - is a technical inevitability (within a couple hundred years). But I agree, explaining human history, all religions, history of Earth as a planet - as a clever simulation, is too simple.

Comment: @TheMatrixEquation-balance -- If by human history you mean the many regrettable and unnecessary things that we do to each other, then, I agree, we can and should look for an explanation. Not laugh, not to weep, nor to hate, but to understand -- and, hopefully, to find a way to end this madness.

Comment: Unfortunately, war is the only reliable tool to move human history, together with technological progress. It always was. The last 70 years of peace is a big anomaly in human history.

Answer (score 1):

Randomness and chaos can both be abundantly accounted for by math, specifically probability theory and complex systems theory. Your assumed dichotomy is totally not valid.

It is *psycologically helpful* tp believe in an intelligible world in which our actions can be meaningful and have positive impacts, sure. But that doesn't make it a requirement for the eotld to be so. You casually use the word 'prove', in regard to Hegel's idea of progress, namely an inevitable iteration towards the Absolute. But proof belongs in math. And the concept of progress, is not math.

How progress vs a non-computable world relate to the Simulation Hypothesis I cannot see. The issue of being in a simulation is solved by focusing on the phenomenology - ie what do we currently have evidence for? 'Reality', whether it turns out to be different to it's appearance or not, is simply what we currently have evidence for. We could be in the mind of god, or the Matrix, or all riding on an invisible pink unicorn. But if you don't turn to evidence, all such speculations are equal.

> "If money constituted the lifeblood of the economy, then human pain
> would be the main currency of human history."

What kind of non-sequitor deepity is that? You are jumbling up economics, money, wellbeing and history in a way that cannot be called sensible.

Consider for instance. The dramatic decrease in infant mortality has probably reduced human misery more than almost anything else. We got progress, and it didn't cost us pain, progress and moving away from pain were one and the same.

I see the creation of Israel as positive, as the righting of historic injustice, and moving into a post imperial era of peoples being given rights to self-determination. That took the empires of the world bankrupting themselves to destroy each other. But that doesn't make the Holocaust the toll for necessary progress, any more than infant mortality was a necessary toll gor us to develop a proper understanding of hygiene. We could have done better, we should try to do better.

That is the lesson, not the neccessity of war and genocide to the meagre advances we have made. Now Israel need to right historic injustices too, while facing an enemy with as little chance of winning as the Jewish people had against the Romans. Their challenge is to be in the position the Romans were, and do better. That is the hope of the Hegelian dialectic.

Comment: "But if you don't turn to evidence" - philosophy is not an exact science. This is a logical perception, often without reliable scientific proof.

"We got progress, and it didn't cost us pain" - this is an important point, and one that can be mathematically proven (in the future). "No pain no gain" - is a personal life impression. But it can be applied mathematically to the total per capita human suffering calculations. I would argue that there is more human suffering in the US than in Russia.

Comment: "This is a logical perception, often without reliable scientific proof." No it isn't, empiricism relies on evidence (ie experience) rather than logic (see the Problem of Induction). Logic requires experience first, to be abstracted, it can't precede experience (see Private Language arg). Again, proof belongs in the domain of math. Nothing in science is proven, we only have overwhelming evidence, but even when that puts a claim beyond reasonable doubt the claim is still open to future revision we can't foresee - eg we are in simulation created by far future humans to investigate their past.

Comment: "The Matrix and modern philosophy" - was a course offered at Columbia University (early 00's).  So, this subject of 'technical philosophy'  (similar to Kant's spontaneous activity of understanding) has moved into the main stream.